# Stripe API Charge::retrieve(['amount']) into a currency format with Twig

Tags: php, twig, stripe-payments

I am trying to format the charge amount retrieved from Stripe API. The amount from the `Charge::retrieve(['amount'])` is `14330000`.

Within my `Twig View` i have the following;

```
{{ order.amount | number_format(0, '.', ',') }}
```

Which should produce;

```
143,000
```

But produces;

```
14,300,000
```

I am presuming that Stripe `Charge::retrieve(['amount'])` is a `float`

Any help to format the amount to `143,000` or even `143,000.00` would be good.

Comment: What are you asking?!? The number is 14330000 you want to format it to 143,000 how is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my behalf - should be `14,300,000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order.amount`  may contain cents, you just need to divide it by 100.

```
{{ (order.amount / 100) | number_format(0, '.', ',') }}
```

Are you sure about the unexpected `3`?

See [fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/vxbjqm)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my behalf - `{{ (order.amount / 100) | number_format(0, '.', ',') }}` works great

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/197176).

Comment: 52 seconds and counting mate